# Not enough permissions in MSSQL to check NVARCHAR field length

Tags: sql-server

In MSSQL Server I'm used to the fact that if I call a stored procedure, having only the rights to execute it (is determined by schema name), then the procedure itself has the right to access all objects of my database as the owner.

However, this doesn't seem to cover the means by which I could get the length of a NVARCHAR field.

I tried:

- COL_LENGTH('dbo.TableName', 'ColumnName')
- SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('TableName'), 'ColumnName', 'PRECISION');
- SELECT TOP 1 CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName'

All of them, when used in a stored procedure, return a valid integer if called by the administrator account and NULL if called by an ordinary user.

**I'm against granting SELECT permissions on tables. Tables must remain directly inaccessible to a normal user.**

What to do? I want that a database client knows the current max character length of a specific field and queries it directly from the database in order not to recompile the client on every change.

I would like to use this information in text field validation to prevent the save button from being clicked when the string exceeds its maximum length. Also, I want to display information like "403 characters left" while the user is typing.

Comment: *" then the procedure itself has the right to access all objects of my database as the owner."* This isn't true. Permission chaining works so long as the objects themselves have the same owner. If, for example, the procedure was owned by `dbo` but the table by `Sally`, then permission chaining would not work.

Comment: In regards to the above functions, you need permission to `VIEW` the object; if the `USER` does not have those permissions then `NULL` or an error is returned, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thom, thank you for explaining. All I want to say that stored procedures always had enough permissions, but not in this one case.

Comment: Ok, are there some other means that do not require permission to `VIEW` ?

Comment: I've decided to hardcode the desired integer value into the stored procedure output. In this case I still don't have to recompile and deploy every client copy and only have to modify the stored procedure after changing the column length. Ant I do don't need to grant permissions unneccessarily.

Comment: A reasonable question is what you intend to do with this information when you have it. Anything involving dynamic SQL is likely to run into similar permission issues. If you really need nothing more than the metadata, you can [sign the procedure with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate) that has the required permissions. A less secure shortcut is to use `EXECUTE AS`. Both of these techniques generally allow procedures to do things their callers would otherwise not have permission for.

Comment: Another possible approach is to create a view in a dedicated schema that does a `SELECT TOP(0) allowed_column, another_allowed_column FROM table` and grant users `SELECT` (or `VIEW DEFINITION`) on the entire schema (`GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::MyPublicMetadataForEveryone TO public`); this would not allow them to see any data you don't want them to see, but without having to micromanage permissions.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the question "A reasonable question is what you intend to do with this information when you have it". I described in the question what I want to do with it.

Comment: "I want that a database client knows the current max character length of a specific field" doesn't indicate what the client will *do* with that maximum length. If what it does is not related to the database directly (maybe it uses it to size a textbox?), then it's fine, but otherwise just answering the question of how to get the length without additional permissions might only be the beginning of your permission problems, hence the follow-up.

Comment: *""I want that a database client knows the current max character length of a specific field"* then, honestly, `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` seems the "better™" solution here.

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, I want to use this information in text field validation to prevent clicking the "Save" button if the string exceeds its maximum length. Also I want to display an information like "403 characters left" as the user is typing.

Comment: Then presumably you might be calling another stored procedure to actually save the data (since you don't want to give users direct rights on tables)? If so then using the information in `sys.parameters` is another option (`select * from sys.parameters where object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyInsertProc')`), although this is less comfortable than getting metadata for views or queries (for starters, you have to take care of dividing the `max_length` by 2 for `NVARCHAR` types yourself, that sort of nonsense).

Comment: What if you insert into a temp table and get the column length from that? .. select top(0) * into #tmp…COL_LENGTH('tempdb..#tmp', 'ColumnName')

Comment: lptr: Yes, I could even create a job that updates a specific table, say, once a day, but I decided to hardcode the value into the stored procedure because I found more places than just the column length and the stored procedure parameter where the text length is constrained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a `USER` to be able to see things like the length of a column they need to be able to `VIEW` the table's `DEFINITION`. Without that they cannot do this.

In the example below I demonstrate granting the `USER` the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission to the schema, however, you may choose to grant it to specific objects. You may also want to use a `ROLE` rather than explicitly giving permission to a `USER`.

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create a sample user
CREATE USER Sally WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
--Create a sampel data with a single row
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY, SomeString nvarchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeString)
VALUES(N'abc')
GO
--Example proc to get data
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProc @ID int AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT SomeString
    FROM dbo.SomeTable
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;
GO
--Proc that tries to get the definition from the table
CREATE PROC dbo.GetSomeStringLen AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT COL_LENGTH(N'dbo.SomeTable', N'SomeString') AS Col_length,
           COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeTable'), N'SomeString', 'PRECISION') AS ColumnProperty;

END;
GO
--Grant execute on the Procs
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.SomeProc TO Sally;
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.GetSomeStringLen TO Sally;
GO
--Run as Sally
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Sally';
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable; --Fails
GO
EXEC dbo.SomeProc @ID = 1; --Woprks
GO
EXEC dbo.GetSomeStringLen; --Returns NULL
GO
--Returns no rows
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeTable');
GO
--Revert to dbo
REVERT;
GO
--Give view definition permissions on dbo to Sally
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO Sally;
GO
--Run as Sally
EXECUTE AS USER = 'Sally';
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable; --Fails
GO
EXEC dbo.SomeProc @ID = 1; --Works
GO
EXEC dbo.GetSomeStringLen; --Works
GO
--Returns 2 rows
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SomeTable');
GO
--Revert to dbo
REVERT;
GO

--Clean up
DROP PROC dbo.GetSomeStringLen;
DROP PROC dbo.SomeProc;
DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
DROP USER Sally;
```

Of course there are other methods. One would be as [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868227/not-enough-permissions-in-mssql-to-check-nvarchar-field-length#comment133823531_75868227) as use a signed procedure. This, likely, is a better method, especially if you don't want your users to be able to get the definition on your objects without you having much more control over their actions.

There is, however, another option. You *could* make use of `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`, which *doesn't* require `VIEW DEFINITION`. Instead what you do is `EXEC` the procedure inside the function, and that gives you the underlying definition:

```sql
SELECT max_length
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'EXEC dbo.SomeProc',NULL, NULL)
WHERE name = N'SomeString';
```